# PowerShell scripts to install nuget packages

Tags: .net, powershell, nuget

Whenever I start a project I want to install the NuGet packages Elmah, Glimpse, MvcScaffolding, Squishit and ... - well those are the ones I am aware of. Maybe I should be installing others as well?

Anyway, instead of having to remember all these it would be good to put this all in a script and all I have to do is run that. However, this is the first time I have come into contact with PowerShell and I am not sure how to do this.

I have looked at an example project and the script looks simple enough, but I am confused as to why there is a need to install the package with a .test suffix? Why also the -Project parameter?

For example,

```
Install-Package SqlServerCompact -Project MileageStats.Data.SqlCe
Install-Package SqlServerCompact -Project MileageStats.Data.SqlCe.tests
```

I have done a Google search to find out more, but I think I am looking in the wrong places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a project template with the required NuGet packages, as Fabrice has already suggested, is probably the approach I would take. To get the latest versions of the NuGet packages you could use the [NuGet Package Updater](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NuGetPackageUpdater) package. That would get around the project template currently only supporting installing a specific version of a NuGet package.

Alternatively you can store useful PowerShell scripts inside the [NuGet profile](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console#Setting_up_a_NuGet_Powershell_Profile). Create a file called **NuGet_profile.ps1** in the **%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell** directory (e.g. C:\Users[YourUserName]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\NuGet_profile.ps1).

Inside the NuGet_profile.ps1 you can add PowerShell functions that you can call from the Package Manager Console window inside Visual Studio. You will need to restart Visual Studio before the functions can be called. An example NuGet_profile.ps1 file is shown below.

```
function Install-StandardPackages {
    param(
        [Parameter(position=0, mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$projectName
    )

    Install-Package elmah -ProjectName $projectName
    Install-Package SqlServerCompact -ProjectName $projectName
}

function Install-StandardPackagesForAllProjects {
    foreach ($project in Get-Project -all) {
        Install-StandardPackages $project.Name
    }
}
```

Now with these functions defined you could run the following in the Package Manager Console to install elmah and SqlServerCompact into a project called MyProject.

```
Install-StandardPackages MyProject
```

Or you could install elmah and SqlServerCompact into all projects in the currently open solution by running the following in the Package Manager Console.

```
Install-StandardPackagesForAllProjects
```

The -ProjectName parameter in the Install-Package command is used to specify the name of the project that the package will be installed into. The tests suffix looks like it is part of the name of the project containing unit tests.

Comment: Thank you, this works and I can follow what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for you might be to create a meta nuget package that you host in a local repository. You create a nuget package with dependencies on all the different packages that you want to have for your specific project setup. All you have to do is to install the meta package, which in it's turn will install all dependencies.

Comment: I realized a problem with my proposed solution. Nuget only looks in one package source, which means that the meta package needs to be published at the the same location as the dependencies. In this case it would mean that you have to download the packages to a local package repository.

Comment: I am new to this kind of thing. Do you have any good links I can look at?

Comment: Regarding creating a package it's described here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package . Publishing on a local share is just a matter of creating a UNC file share and put the nupkg files there and set up a new package source in VS that points to the file share.

Comment: Please understand that I really am a beginner on all this. What I understand you are suggesting is that I need to locate the powershell script in a location that everyone can access; a UNC file share. That sounds like a good idea. I do not know how to do that. In your answer you are referring to dependencies and I do not know what you have in mind here. And you are talking about a package whilst I have in mind a script that I can run in Package Manager Console. My impression is that a package is required because a script does not deal with the dependencies?

Comment: The reason I do not have dependencies on the agenda is that the packages I want to download are not dependent on each other, as far as I am aware (see orginal question). Maybe that will change in the future of course.

Comment: @arame3333 - my suggestion was to create a new nuget package. Packages can have dependencies on other packages. Having a dependency will cause the dependency to be installed when installing the dependent package. A meta package is a package without any real content, it just has dependencies. The downside of this approach is that you would have to host all packages locally and thus lose the advantage of having the latest versions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create your own mvc3 project template in which you can specify your preferred Nuget packages. 
To do so you should have a look at Phil Haack [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx)

Comment: Interesting approach - too bad it's limited to having the packages locally and having to specify an exact version. Hopefully it's remedied in a future version.